# Why did Steam Pre-Load Rainbow Six Siege?

Tags: steam, rainbow-six-siege

I have two different Steam accounts but I only used one of them until I wanted to download Rainbow Six Siege to my Computer. I opened my other Account (which has Rainbow 6 Siege) and downloaded the game, but after it finished and I tried playing it, nothing happens because the game is only pre-loaded.

Why does that happen and how do I actually download the game?

Comment: Not sure how you manage to pre load a purchased and already released game. Pre loading is for games that are not yet released so you can pre order, and download the game ahead of time so you can begin playing upon its release date without waiting.

Comment: Are you sure that you completely downloaded the game? Rainbow six siege allows you to launch the game before it is completely downloaded. If it is only partially downloaded you should be able to play the single player situations, but none of the multiplayer game modes. Are you able to launch the game and play the situations?

Answer (score 0):

It mays seem a bit dumb, but have you contacted the support ? 
You're not supposed to pre-load already published games whatsoever, and it should have began the download for the full version as soon as you loaded Steam.